# Raspberry 3, python and shared libraries

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

I want to code something which can remote this robot: Dobot Magician http://dobot.cc/dobot-magician/product-overview.html. 
I have a Raspberry 3 and I downloaded the precompiled DLL for Linux on Dobot's website (Dobot Demo v2.0 http://dobot.cc/download-center/dobot-magician.html) and unfortunately, I can not load the DLL for Linux (file .so) with the function dlopen or cdll.LoadLibrary() on Python. 
The error is :

```
OSError: libDobotDll.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I added the folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I tried on Ubuntu 64 bits VM and I got a different error message:

```
libDobotDll.so.1.0.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I don't know how I can deal with it.
Is there somebody can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: after you added the folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, did you start a new shell? That should work. I would focus on making sure you have tried everyting to  see why that isn't working. But you may eventually wind up getting the same 2nd error, but then you have to go back to the robot site and ask if there is another version, or get the source code and build the `.so|.dll` for the correct architecture. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
I will try to start a new shell as you suggest. 

I have the source code but I have no Makefile. I think they code and build with visual studio. :/
For the windows Dll, they give the 32 and 64 bits version and only one version for Linux. 
I sent a mail to the company, I am waiting for the answer.